# Angular environment variable in index.html file

Tags: angular, google-maps

I would like to put environment variable from main.ts in index.html `<script src="...">` tag. Index.html look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>RoadFaultReporter</title>
        <base href="./" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the place of **MY_KEY** in `<script src="">` I would like to place a key from variable - environment.googleMapsApi. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not, but you can do it the Angular way; By adding a provided to AppModule you force the whole app initialization to wait until google maps are loaded.

The code below is the one I created. I created it before the [official package](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader) was created but I still use mine as it is without dependency and 450 lines shorter.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    //...
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useValue: () => loadGoogleMaps(environment.googleMapsKey),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

loadGoogleMaps

```
const CALLBACK_NAME = 'initMap';

export enum GoogleMapsLibraries {
    /** provides a graphical interface for users to draw polygons, rectangles, polylines, circles, and markers on the map. Consult the [Drawing library documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) for more information. */
    drawing = 'drawing',
    /** includes utility functions for calculating scalar geometric values (such as distance and area) on the surface of the earth. Consult the [Geometry library documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) for more information. */
    geometry = 'geometry',
    /** shows users key places of interest near a location that you specify. Consult the Local [Context library documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/local-context) for more information. */
    localContext = 'localContext',
    /** enables your application to search for places such as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest, within a defined area. Consult the [Places library documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) for more information. */
    places = 'places',
    /** provides heatmaps for visual representation of data. Consult the [Visualization library documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization) for more information. */
    visualization = 'visualization',
};

export function loadGoogleMaps(googleMapsKey: string, libraries: GoogleMapsLibraries[] = []) {
    if (!window) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        function onError(err?: any) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
            (window as any)[CALLBACK_NAME] = () => {}; // Set the on load callback to a no-op
            scriptElement.removeEventListener('error', onError);
            reject(err || new Error('Could not load the Google Maps API'));
        }

        // Reject the promise after a timeout
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => onError(), 10000);

        // Hook up the on load callback
        (window as any)[CALLBACK_NAME] = () => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            scriptElement.removeEventListener('error', onError);
            resolve();
            delete (window as any)[CALLBACK_NAME];
        };

        // Deduplicate libraries
        libraries = [...new Set(libraries)];

        // Prepare the `script` tag to be inserted into the page
        const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.addEventListener('error', onError);
        scriptElement.async = true;
        scriptElement.defer = true;
        scriptElement.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleMapsKey}&region=Cz&language=cs&callback=${CALLBACK_NAME}&libraries=${libraries.join(',')}`;
        document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
    });
}
```

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER works with `useValue`, not `useFactory`?

Comment: @robert this works in my case, thought after looking into docs, the correct way may be to pass it to a factory...